# how to run 32 bit dll on a 64 bit windows 10 machine using java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, windows-10

I am using windows 10
my output of java -version is

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I get following error om running this program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include\win32\test.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
        at JNITest.<clinit>(JNITest.java:5)
```

My program is

```
public class JNITest {
   static{
     // System.load("/home/user1/
       //  JNI_project/mynativelib.so");
      System.load("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_25\\include\\win32\\test.dll");
   }
  // public native void  LOSSGREENAMPT(TIMEINTERVAL,  STARTINITIALLOSS,double ENDINITIALLOSS,double MOISTUREDEFICIT, double SUCTION,double  CONDUCTIVITY, double STARTINFILTRATION,double  FINALINFILTRATION, double IMPERVIOUSAREARATIO,int NUMBERPRECIP, double PRECIP(1),double  EXCESS(1),int ERRORCODE[4], char ERRORMESSAGE[60],char L_errorMessage[60]); 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     JNITest test=new JNITest();
      //test.greet();
   }
}
```

Comment: Not. Find a 64 bit one.

Comment: my dll file is libhydro.dll https://www.crwr.utexas.edu/gis/gishydro03/LibHydro/LibHydro.htm which is a 32 bit one

Comment: Running the 32-bit version of Java could work.

Comment: @Roger Gustavsson is there no other way by keeping jdk as 64 bit

Comment: No, I don't think so. Only what Stultulske suggested, get a 64-bit version of the dll.

Comment: Is there any other alternative method to make 32 bit dll to work on 64 bit machine

Comment: There's no problem with running 32-bit Java on 64-bit Windows. You can also have both 32-bit and 64-bit Java installed at the same time on the same machine. So you use 32-bit Java for the program that uses the 32-bit dll and you can use 64-bit Java for all other programs.